# How to put FlowLayout in new line?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, border-layout, flowlayout

I am new to Swing, but as I was doing this, I am not sure why this prints everything in same line. I want to use Border Layout to print them in new line. I tried it but not getting the right result.

Currently it's printing like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNG6s.png)

I want it to print in this order:

- Paper Sizes: BOX
- Copy Sides: BOX
- ..

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: your code is in Swing not JavaFX

Comment: I suggest using [GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) rather than `FlowLayout`. There are also third party layout managers like [FormLayout](https://www.formdev.com/jformdesigner/doc/layouts/formlayout/). Do you know about the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)? I don't think making all your _Swing_ components static fields of class `Main` is a good idea.

Comment: hi there, I am not sure about the Event Dispatch Thread, as I just started learning Swing.

Comment: The Oracle tutorial [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) will help you learn Swing the correct way.  Skip the Netbeans section.

Comment: Get rid of all the static variables. They are being used incorrectly. Read the Swing tutorial. Download some of the demo classes an modify the demo code. The code will be better structured and show you have to better create a Swing GUI.